# The related concepts to a special statement

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I saw the following statement later but I don't know it is true or not and I don't remember its reference:

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty sets and $G$ is a group with the generating set $A$ and $H$ is a group with the generating set $B$. Also suppose that $H\le G$. If for every $g\in A\cup A^{-1}$ and $h\in B$, $g^{-1} h g \in B$, then $H \trianglelefteq G$.

I need the reference of the above statement. Also, I am looking for references that contain some facts similar to the above statement.

I will appreciate any comments and answers.

Comment: It's true. You can prove it by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in G, h \in H$,  $h = \prod b_i, \ g = \prod a_i$  Form $$g h g^{-1} = \prod a_i \prod b_i \prod a_i^{-1} = a_1 \cdots (a_n b_1 a_n^{-1}) (a_n b_2 \cdots b_{k-1} a_n^{-1})( a_n b_k a_n^{-1})\cdots a_1^{-1}$$.  In the above product the $(a_n b_i a_n^{-1}$)'s of course all equal some $b_i'$.  Repeat the process until the entire product is composed of $b_i'$s.  This shows that $ghg^{-1} \in H$, and we're done.

We can conclude that your conjecture is correct for the post part.  <strike>You don't need $\forall g \in A \cup A^{-1}$ but only $ \forall g \in A$.  And</strike>  You don't need to state that $A,B$ are non-empty since you've said they're generating sets.

Comment: For infinite groups the $A\cup A^{-1}$ hypothesis may be required because the inverse of a generator could possibly not be expressible as a power of a generator (i.e. it could be of infinite order).

Comment: @MattSamuel I don't see what that has to do with anything.  $a^{-1}$ isn't an expression of power, it's a convention of writing the inverses by.

Comment: If you know that $a^{-1}ba\in B$ for all $a\in A$, that doesn't necessarily mean $aba^{-1}\in B$ for all $a\in A$, because there may be elements of the group that cannot be expressed as a product of elements of $A$. A generating set of a group is not like a generating set of a monoid, you may need to take inverses of the generators.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your answer. It is also important for me to have some good references about some similar statements.

Comment: Matt Samuel is correct. You definitely need $\forall g \in A \cup A^{-1}$,